# Push values to a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

In the following code I am trying to add all PNG's to `screenshot` object

```
common.getFilesInFolder(reportDir, '.png', function(err, PNGs) {
        if(!err && PNGs.length > 0){
          for(var i=0; i< PNGs.length; i++) {
            report[test[0]].screenshot[id] = PNGs[i];
          }
        }
        callback(null, report);
      });
```

But, while iterating the report object `.report[test[0]].screenshot[0]` is getting `undefined`

Comment: what (if anything) does your error console say?  Where are the declarations of `id`, `test[]` and `tests[]` ?

Comment: just side note not related to question - if You're doing such callback function (and it looks like You want typical nodejs async func) in node.js it doesnt mean its asynchronous and not blocking. it is. You have to wrap it in setTimeout() to make it async and non blocking.

Comment: that is a mistake....i forgot to delelte that line

Comment: @Jarema at this level I think your comment will just confuse the OP...

Comment: and what about `id`?  Is that supposed to be `i`, perhaps?

Comment: @Alnitak You might be right, but im afraid that hitting that "blocking problem" later might be also very confusing. I would rather say to OP - when You think, that You know javascript quite well, checkout that comment once again :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

1. That `test`, `test[0]` and `report[test[0]]` are defined in an outer scope
2. That `screenshot[id]` is supposed to read `screenshot[i]` (since otherwise you're overwriting the same element over and over in each iteration)
3. And that the resulting code is there just supposed to copy the array `PNGs` into the `.screenshot` property of `report[test[0]]`:

Then you can remove the loop and just take a copy of the array:

```
report[test[0]].screenshot = PNGs.slice(0);
```

You may even simply be able to copy the *reference* to the array, if nothing else is going to modify it:

```
report[test[0]].screenshot = PNGs;
```

Comment: plese put your annswer here.. so that i can accept.ut telling i need to remove the for llop?

Answer (score 0):

According to this snippet of code, report[] isn't defined at all as an array or object. Perhaps you just need

```
var report=[]; // array
```

or

```
var report={}; // object
```

as the first line of the function?

Also test[] isn't defined

Comment: it's perfectly possible that `report` could be an object - it depends on the (unspecified) key format.

Comment: i neeed to push values to screeshot object..is it posssible....??ice  in` {screenshot:[image1,image2]}` this format

Comment: @Altinak true - have modified answer.

Comment: @Psl yes, you can store image objects in an array. However you haven't said in the code what the variable PNGs is - how it's defined. I think you need a bit more context tot the question before it can be answered fully- eg how all variables are defined.